# Modify column data before a specific character using Regex in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to modify the Address column data by removing all the characters before the comma.

Sample data:

```
                       **ADDRESS**
0                    Ksfc Layout,Bangalore
1                Vishweshwara Nagar,Mysore
2                         Jigani,Bangalore
3              Sector-1 Vaishali,Ghaziabad
4                         New Town,Kolkata
```

Expected Output:

```
                      **ADDRESS**
0                        Bangalore
1                        Mysore
2                        Bangalore
3                        Ghaziabad
4                        Kolkata
```

I tried this code but it's not working can someone correct the code?

```
import pandas as pd
import regex as re

data = pd.read_csv("train.csv")

data.ADDRESS.replace(re.sub(r'.*,',"", data.ADDRESS), regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data.ADDRESS = data.ADDRESS.str.split(',').str[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without a regex:

```
def removeFirst(x):
    return x.split(",")[-1]

df['ADDRESS'] = df['ADDRESS'].apply(removeFirst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this without Regex:

```
data['ADDRESS'] = data['ADDRESS'].str.split(',').str[-1]
```

Comment: @MayankPorwal you and me answered just same time, just in split of seconds, my iPhone safari browser where I am in currently does not refresh page realtime where in full site it I think does in my computers, so I don't get notified,  it is a very normal issue in high traffic tags

Comment: @WasifHasan - one minute difference, not *split-seconds*.

Comment: @wwii my current internet connection is slow too, on first attempt it failed, So I went one page back, I needed to sit closer to the router, and then posted back

Answer (score 0):

Use `Series.str.replace`:

```py
data['ADDRESS'] = data['ADDRESS'].str.replace(r'.*,', '')
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/7bFcEP/1)